# x509: certificate signed by unknown authority CI CD with Azure DevOps

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I'm starting using a build in Azure DevOps with Https on my endpoints then i receive:

2020-07-31T17:27:17.8377456Z [Error] Get "//////////////////////////////api/security/encryptedPassword": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

2020-07-31T17:27:17.8478624Z ##[error]Error occurred while executing task:
Error: Command failed: D:\Builds_toolsCache_jfrog\current\jfrog.exe rt c "visual-studio-web_20200731.2_nuget_restoreResolve" --url="///////////////////////artifactory" --interactive=false --user=*** --password=***
2020-07-31T17:27:17.8526954Z ##[section]Finalisation : Artifactory NuGet restore

JFrog CLI version: 1.38.2
Artifactory pro v6.16.0 on premise

So i'm asking if there is any jfrog native support of certificates with jfrog cli?

Thank you !
ALI

Comment: Ali, looking at the error snippet it looks like the certificates to be self signed. in that case I recommend you to import the certificates to securty/certs directory. You can get more information around this in this wiki https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-NotUsingaPublicCA(CertificateAuthority)?

Answer (score 1):

Following this question, we added [this](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Azure+DevOps+Extension#ArtifactoryAzureDevOpsExtension-NotUsingaPublicCA(CertificateAuthority)?) section to Artifactory Azure DevOps Extension documentation.